# cxf 2way ssl not webservice give Cannot create a secure XMLInputFactory

Tags: java, web-services, ssl, cxf

In my client of a web service which developed by cxf like [this](http://aruld.info/programming-ssl-for-jetty-based-cxf-services/), and is supposed to be a 2-way ssl implementation I get the following exception.

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Cannot create a secure XMLInputFactory
```

Unless I set the following environment property with value 1.

```
org.apache.cxf.stax.allowInsecureParser
```

But I guess it means that the connection will be insecure.
Am I right?

Comment: Maybe you can add a bit more information about the environment you use. However maybe this helps: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20114945/cxf-web-service-client-cannot-create-a-secure-xmlinputfactory

Answer (score 0):

That exception has nothing to do with SSL.

If your service consumes XML content and is accessed by untrusted clients (for example, it is exposed to the Internet), it will be vulnerable to an [XXE attack](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/XML_External_Entity_%28XXE%29_Processing). To mitigate, you need to have Woodstox 4.2.0 or later on the classpath. See [WSTX-285](http://jira.codehaus.org/browse/WSTX-285).

If your service doesn't accept XML content, you should be OK.

Answer (score 0):

I added these three lines and worked fine

Properties props = System.getProperties(); props.setProperty("org.apache.cxf.stax.allowInsecureParser", "1"); props.setProperty("UseSunHttpHandler", "true");

Comment: Please present code that is more than a tiny snippet as a code block. Can you shed some light on the implications of `System.getProperties().setProperty("org.apache.cxf.stax.allowInsecureParser", "1");`? (_insecure_?!) - Welcome to Stack Exchange!

Comment: Just before invoking the web service