# Apache CXF dependencies

Tags: java, cxf

We are in the process of upgrading our JDK(Tomcat), we upgraded CXF to 3.2.12 from 2.4.0 and we were getting an error which was fixed by adding `-Dorg.apache.cxf.stax.allowInsecureParser=1` as an JVM argument based on this [CXF web service client: "Cannot create a secure XMLInputFactory"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20114945/cxf-web-service-client-cannot-create-a-secure-xmlinputfactory) but I don't think its the right way to do. Can anybody suggest any other plausible solutions?

```
javax.xml.ws.soap.SOAPFaultException: Cannot create a secure XMLInputFactory
    at org.apache.cxf.jaxws.JaxWsClientProxy.invoke(JaxWsClientProxy.java:157)
    at $Proxy38.printString(Unknown Source)
    at ExampleNmsWebServiceClient.printString(ExampleNmsWebServiceClient.java:29)
    at ExampleNmsWebServiceClient.main(ExampleNmsWebServiceClient.java:40)
Caused by: org.apache.cxf.binding.soap.SoapFault: Cannot create a secure XMLInputFactory
    at org.apache.cxf.binding.soap.interceptor.Soap11FaultInInterceptor.unmarshalFault(Soap11FaultInInterceptor.java:84)
    at org.apache.cxf.binding.soap.interceptor.Soap11FaultInInterceptor.handleMessage(Soap11FaultInInterceptor.java:51)
    at org.apache.cxf.binding.soap.interceptor.Soap11FaultInInterceptor.handleMessage(Soap11FaultInInterceptor.java:40)
    at org.apache.cxf.phase.PhaseInterceptorChain.doIntercept(PhaseInterceptorChain.java:272)
    at org.apache.cxf.interceptor.AbstractFaultChainInitiatorObserver.onMessage(AbstractFaultChainInitiatorObserver.java:113)
    at org.apache.cxf.binding.soap.interceptor.CheckFaultInterceptor.handleMessage(CheckFaultInterceptor.java:69)
    at org.apache.cxf.binding.soap.interceptor.CheckFaultInterceptor.handleMessage(CheckFaultInterceptor.java:34)
    at org.apache.cxf.phase.PhaseInterceptorChain.doIntercept(PhaseInterceptorChain.java:272)
    at org.apache.cxf.endpoint.ClientImpl.onMessage(ClientImpl.java:835)
    at org.apache.cxf.transport.http.HTTPConduit$WrappedOutputStream.handleResponseInternal(HTTPConduit.java:1606)
    at org.apache.cxf.transport.http.HTTPConduit$WrappedOutputStream.handleResponse(HTTPConduit.java:1502)
    at org.apache.cxf.transport.http.HTTPConduit$WrappedOutputStream.close(HTTPConduit.java:1309)
    at org.apache.cxf.transport.AbstractConduit.close(AbstractConduit.java:56)
    at org.apache.cxf.transport.http.HTTPConduit.close(HTTPConduit.java:627)
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to add Woodstox to the classpath, see the accepted answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/24603135/3745288

Comment: It would be better to flag post for duplicate. Your answer does not provide any additional context.